# Svelte transition 'jumps' animation

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit application with a two divs with text. My goal is to add a `in:fly` animation to the text divs along with an easing function. However, at the end of the easing animation, the animation 'skips' or something weird happened. The ease function does not complete the animation. Here's a gif of the animation

[image: gif of bug]

This is the code I have for this

```html
<script>
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { circOut } from 'svelte/easing';

    let mounted = false;

    onMount(() => {
        mounted = true;
    });
</script>

{#if mounted}
    <main class="w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <div class="w-full max-w-7xl flex">

            <div class="w-3/4 flex flex-col gap-3">
                <!-- Text 1 -->
                <div class="h-40 relative overflow-hidden">
                    <div
                        class="absolute inset-0 text-9xl"
                        in:fly={{ y: 150, duration: 1100, easing: circOut }}
                    >
                        Some
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text 1 -->
                <div class="h-40 relative overflow-hidden">
                    <div
                        class="absolute inset-0 text-9xl"
                        in:fly={{ y: 150, duration: 1000, delay: 100, easing: circOut }}
                    >
                        Title
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="w-1/4 bg-blue-300" />
        </div>
    </main>
{/if}
```

This does not happen when the page is hot-refreshed after saving the file.

- I've tried using other ease functions as well but the result is the same
- I've tried removing the absolute positioning of the `div`s with no luck as well

[image]

**Edit:** I tried it with just one text element but the issue persists.

```html
<script>
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { circOut } from 'svelte/easing';

    let mounted = false;

    onMount(() => {
        mounted = true;
    });
</script>

{#if mounted}
    <div class="text-9xl" in:fly={{ y: 150, duration: 1100, easing: circOut }}>Text</div>
{/if}
```

**Edit 2:**

- I added a MRE to this [repository](https://github.com/notnavindu/easing-bug). ([Hosted](https://easing-bug.vercel.app/))
- Issue persists on Chrome, Chrome guest mode, Chrome for Android.
- Does NOT happen on Firefox

**Edit 3**

- It happens even without the easing function. (Initially thought it was caused by the ease function)

Comment: If you remove the second bit of text, does the first still jump?

Comment: Yes it happens even with one text

Comment: Does removing all classes make a difference?

Comment: @Corrl I tried removing all classes, also removed tailwind imports. But no luck

Comment: Can't reproduce this [in the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/15e0981993d34744b7558d7baadc3f40?version=3.55.1); runs smooth in Chrome & Firefox. Have you tried a guest profile in Chrome? Might just be an extension messing stuff up.

Comment: @H.B. The REPL you sent seems to be working smoothly for me too. I added a MRE code and the hosted link to the question. Can you check if it runs smoothly for you?

Comment: Can confirm that it jumps in Chrome and not FF.

Comment: I came to find [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/) is the culprit for a layout shift I spent months trying to fix. That browser extension injects a bunch of markup into the DOM to do its detection and analysis.

Comment: Thanks @dgrebb. Were you able to find a way to get rid of it?

Comment: @notnavindu there are a few things to look out for. Does one element have margin/padding that the transitioning-to element does not? Margins in general seem weird on transition, especially in flex layouts. After testing all of these, it 100% came down to removing the browser extension.